# Getting data from database in Service

Tags: java, android, sqlite, oop, mobile

I have been trying for days but it seems that i cant find the solution i am trying to get value from the database in a services but my app just crashes. But the same code works in the activity but not on a background services.

this is the code

```
   public class Services1 extends Service {
    Context cont = this;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public void onCreates() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String go = "running";

    Toast.makeText(cont, go, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onCreate();
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}


    public void onStartCommand(Intent intent, String Number, String Body ) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        SmsManager  smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

         String phoneNo = Number;
            String sms = Body;

        Data obj = new Data(this);

    //  String dar = obj.Data1("1").toString();


        try{
            SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("FinalDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT REPLAYS FROM Rtm WHERE ID = 1", null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            String dar = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("REPLAYS"));

                String api = "Yeap service started";

                String rep = sms.replace(phoneNo+" :", "");
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, dar, null, null);

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Some Problem Here");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




        }







}
```

i have not syntax error. but when i call the onstartcommand without database it works fine but when using database it does not work app crashes i have also tried

```
        Data obj = new Data(this);

            String dar = obj.Data1("1").toString(); // getting value from my SQLitehelper class it works in activity but not in service.
```

So my question is that the wrong way of retrieving database in the services or is there a better way.

my sqlitehelper class

```
public class Data  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
 static String Database_Name = "FinalDB";
static int Database_Version = 3;
public Data(Context context) {
    super(context, Database_Name, null, Database_Version);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public String Data1(String id)
{


    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT REPLAYS FROM Rtm WHERE ID = +"+id, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    String repl = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("REPLAYS"));



    return repl;
}
```

my broadcaster class

```
   public class BroadCastRecivers extends BroadcastReceiver{

static String from;
static String body;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context cont, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method 

//  SmsManager  smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();


        // TODO Auto-generated method s
          //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";            
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
           from  =   str  =  msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();              
                str += " :";
           body =  str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";

            }
            //---display the new SMS message---
        //    Toast.makeText(cont, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Services1 obj = new Services1();

            obj.onStartCommand(intent, from, body);



  }
}


   }
```

Comment: Too much whitespace makes this code hard to read, I suggest re-formatting the code....

Answer (score 1):

Change your Select Query as:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT REPLAYS FROM Rtm WHERE ID = "+id, null);
```

because currently you are passing `+`(PLUS) with ID in where clause

and Start your service using `startService` instead of calling `onStartCommand` manually as:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(cont,Services1.class);
intent.putExtra("from",from);
intent.putExtra("body",body);
cont.startService(intent);
```

get `from` and `body` value in Services1 `onStartCommand` using `intent.getStringExtra`

Comment: @MohammedZeeshan : Post your latest log with question

Comment: @MohammedZeeshan : you have lots  of issue in Services1 . to solve some just add `@Override ` to override default Service class methods

Comment: there is nothing in my logcat except for 
01-14 16:21:48.289: I/System.out(429): Thread running null
01-14 16:36:01.781: I/System.out(464): Thread running null
01-14 16:36:11.549: I/System.out(464): Thread running null

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your service creation. Change

```
    public void onCreates() {
```

with

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
```